# Running vscode debugger for c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to run the following launch.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "C++ Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.out",
            "args": ["main.out", "00-input.txt"],
            "environment": [{ "name": "config", "value": "Debug" }],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

However when a run `C/C++: Build and Debug Active File` it doesn't run this setup, it runs some sort of default, but I've been unsuccessful in finding how to to launch this configuration.

[This](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) has a lot of information on what all the configurations do but it doesn't appear to have information on how to launch the desired configuration.

Comment: Since your configuration does not have a "dependsOn" task defined, you need to prepare the `main.out` file before you launch your debugging session in the `Run and Debug` panel or by simply using the shortcut `F5`.

Comment: You say that you are "unsuccessful to launch this configuration". Can you elaborate? Are you getting an error, or the application stops responding?